# Adding a button to the right side of a UISearchBar with AutoLayout: "Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews"

Tags: ios, uibutton, uisearchbar, autolayout

On ios6, I'm trying to perform the following:

```
UIButton *shortcutButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[shortcutButton setTitle:@"Shortcut" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[shortcutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createShortcut) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[shortcutButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 20)];
[self.searchBar addSubview:shortcutButton];

[shortcutButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

NSMutableArray *searchBarConstraints = [NSMutableArray array];

[searchBarConstraints addObject: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.searchBar
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:shortcutButton
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                             multiplier:1
                                                               constant:0]];

[searchBarConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[shortcutButton]-35-|"
                                                                                  options:0
                                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                                    views:@{ @"shortcutButton" : shortcutButton  ,  @"view" : self.view }]];
[self.searchBar addConstraints:searchBarConstraints];
```

This causes a crash with the error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UISearchBar layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UIView.m:5776
Uncaught exception: Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UISearchBar's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.
```

I am programmatically creating a UISearchbar and trying to insert a UIButton at the right side of the searchbar.  Is there any way to handle this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

yahuuu i found solution.
Try put you setup constraints logic into didMoveToSuperview method.
I think it's related with setting constraints before load all your views on hierarchy.
Or just call [super layoutSubviews]; after setup Constraints